# ASP.NET Core equivalent of ASP.NET MVC 5's HttpException

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, httpexception

In ASP.NET MVC 5 you could throw a [HttpException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpexception) with a HTTP code and this would set the response like so:

```
throw new HttpException((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Bad Request.");
```

`HttpException` does not exist in ASP.NET Core. What is the equivalent code?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I implemented my own `HttpException` and supporting middleware which catches all `HttpException`'s and turns them into the corresponding error response. A short extract can be seen below. You can also use the [Boxed.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Boxed.AspNetCore/) Nuget package.

## Usage Example in Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application)
{
    application.UseIISPlatformHandler();

    application.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");
    application.UseHttpException();

    application.UseMvc();
}
```

## Extension Method

```
public static class ApplicationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseHttpException(this IApplicationBuilder application)
    {
        return application.UseMiddleware<HttpExceptionMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

## Middleware

```
internal class HttpExceptionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public HttpExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await this.next.Invoke(context);
        }
        catch (HttpException httpException)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = httpException.StatusCode;
            var responseFeature = context.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>();
            responseFeature.ReasonPhrase = httpException.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

## HttpException

```
public class HttpException : Exception
{
    private readonly int httpStatusCode;

    public HttpException(int httpStatusCode)
    {
        this.httpStatusCode = httpStatusCode;
    }

    public HttpException(HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode)
    {
        this.httpStatusCode = (int)httpStatusCode;
    }

    public HttpException(int httpStatusCode, string message) : base(message)
    {
        this.httpStatusCode = httpStatusCode;
    }

    public HttpException(HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode, string message) : base(message)
    {
        this.httpStatusCode = (int)httpStatusCode;
    }

    public HttpException(int httpStatusCode, string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner)
    {
        this.httpStatusCode = httpStatusCode;
    }

    public HttpException(HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode, string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner)
    {
        this.httpStatusCode = (int)httpStatusCode;
    }

    public int StatusCode { get { return this.httpStatusCode; } }
}
```

In the long term, I would advise against using exceptions for returning errors. Exceptions are slower than just returning an error from a method.

Comment: Unfortunately message is not making it to the client. Body is returned as empty :( (Content-Length = 0)

Comment: @StackOverflower Updated

Comment: Something else that worked for me was to use `Response.WriteAsync` to set the body. Thanks

Comment: Like mentioned above, I replaced the catch block body with:

`context.Response.StatusCode = httpException.StatusCode;

                await context.Response.WriteAsync(httpException.Message);`

Comment: Wrapping up all exceptions and turning them into error response may not be a good idea. The exception won't bubble up to Azure Application Insights as exception and Application Insights won't be able to present you with a detailed stack trace for the errors.

Comment: Unfortunately `catch (HttpException httpException)` doesn't catch exceptions thrown in user code. If I set a breakpoint in catch block, it never triggers. Exceptions make debugger stop on them with a message that they weren't caught in user code.

Comment: I would like to return status code from a method, but my methods belong to SOAP, were generated from WSDL files and I have no chance to change anything on their result. Even result belongs to SOAP.

Answer (score 28):

After a [brief chat with @davidfowl](https://twitter.com/YuvalItzchakov/status/614094855367581696), it seems that ASP.NET 5 has no such notion of `HttpException` or `HttpResponseException` that "magically" turn to response messages.

What you can do, is [hook into the ASP.NET 5 pipeline via MiddleWare](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/269/asp-net-5-middleware-or-where-has-my-httpmodule-gone), and create one that handles the exceptions for you.

Here is an example from the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs) of their error handler middleware which will set the response status code to 500 in case of an exception further up the pipeline:

```
public class ErrorHandlerMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ErrorHandlerOptions _options;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public ErrorHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, 
                                  ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
                                  ErrorHandlerOptions options)
    {
        _next = next;
        _options = options;
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ErrorHandlerMiddleware>();
        if (_options.ErrorHandler == null)
        {
            _options.ErrorHandler = _next;
        }
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("An unhandled exception has occurred: " + ex.Message, ex);

            if (context.Response.HasStarted)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("The response has already started, 
                                    the error handler will not be executed.");
                throw;
            }

            PathString originalPath = context.Request.Path;
            if (_options.ErrorHandlingPath.HasValue)
            {
                context.Request.Path = _options.ErrorHandlingPath;
            }
            try
            {
                var errorHandlerFeature = new ErrorHandlerFeature()
                {
                    Error = ex,
                };
                context.SetFeature<IErrorHandlerFeature>(errorHandlerFeature);
                context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                context.Response.Headers.Clear();

                await _options.ErrorHandler(context);
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                _logger.LogError("An exception was thrown attempting
                                  to execute the error handler.", ex2);
            }
            finally
            {
                context.Request.Path = originalPath;
            }

            throw; // Re-throw the original if we couldn't handle it
        }
    }
}
```

And you need to register it with `StartUp.cs`:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
                          IHostingEnvironment env, 
                          ILoggerFactory loggerfactory)
    {
       app.UseMiddleWare<ExceptionHandlerMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this functionality that is temporarily missing in the Beta or is this code we will have to write?

Comment: @Rehan This is what we'll have to write. They don't plan on bringing that functionality to MVC 6. Every hooking will be done via the middleware pipeline.

Comment: Seems like they are omitting a pretty common piece of functionality. They should at least provide the middle-ware, even if they don't apply it by default.

Comment: @RehanSaeed I agree, that is very useful functionality and I use it often as well. The good thing ASP.NET 5 is open source, we can apply that functionality ourselves if we want.

Comment: I'll add your code to [ASP.NET MVC Boilerplate](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6cf50a48-fc1e-4eaf-9e82-0b2a6705ca7d) and enable it by default. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @davidfowl Which extension method?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I use empty ASP.NET 5 Web API and realize nice 500 error page probably come from this diagnostic middleware. **How to replace this middleware or turn off in production?** Does the framework register it upfront before the `Startup.Configure` being called?

Comment: What about adding a custom body to the response? Like a structured JSON error response model?

Comment: @kspearrin `context.Result = new JsonResult(body);`

Comment: Error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ErrorHandlerOptions' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0246)

How to fix this?

Comment: Having freedom to write our own middleware is great, but basic things like throwing exceptions from a HTTP handling framework should be built-in.

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively, if you just want to return an arbitrary status code and aren't concerned with the Exception-based approach, you can use

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400);
```

Update: as of .NET Core RC 2, the Http prefix is dropped. It is now:

```
return new StatusCodeResult(400);
```

Comment: Yes, directly in an action it is surely the best approach. But sometimes, the action call a private method that does a specific work (returning something else than an ActionResult), and sometimes you would like that this method can throw exceptions to produce a response (mainly errors like 400 bad request, 403 forbidden). In this case the exception is a good choice.

Comment: I worked at a place that specifically forbid the new keyword in Controllers (presumably for DI testability reasons, even though we all know these work). So how would you do it then?

Comment: If you want to be subversive and not use the `new` keyword, I suppose `(StatusCodeResult) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(StatusCodeResult), 400);` would do the trick. Or you can create a StatusCodeFactory class that has methods to return new ones.

Answer (score 7):

There is no equivalent in ASP.NET Core itself. As others have said, the way to implement this is with a middleware and your own exceptions.

The [Opw.HttpExceptions.AspNetCore](https://github.com/ofpinewood/http-exceptions) NuGet package does exactly this.

> Middleware and extensions for returning exceptions over HTTP, e.g. as ASP.NET Core Problem Details. Problem Details are a machine-readable format for specifying errors in HTTP API responses based on https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807. But you are not limited to returning exception results as Problem Details, but you can create your own mappers for your own custom formats.

It is configurable and well documented.

Here is the list of provided exceptions out of the box:

##### 4xx

- 400 BadRequestException
- 400 InvalidModelException
- 400 ValidationErrorException<T>
- 400 InvalidFileException
- 401 UnauthorizedException
- 403 ForbiddenException
- 404 NotFoundException
- 404 NotFoundException<T>
- 409 ConflictException
- 409 ProtectedException
- 415 UnsupportedMediaTypeException

##### 5xx

- 500 InternalServerErrorException
- 500 DbErrorException
- 500 SerializationErrorException
- 503 ServiceUnavailableException

Answer (score 6):

The `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controller` base class exposes a `HttpBadRequest(string)` overload which takes an error message to return to the client. So from within a controller action, you could call:

```
return HttpBadRequest("Bad Request.");
```

Ultimately my nose says any private methods called from within a controller action should either be fully http-context-aware and return an `IActionResult`, or perform some other small task completely isolated from the fact that it's inside of an http pipeline. Granted this is my personal opinion, but a class that performs some piece of business logic should not be returning HTTP status codes, and instead should be throwing its own exceptions which can be caught and translated at the controller/action level.

Comment: Agreed but some people may have old MVC 5 apps using `HttpException`. Porting is made much easier if the same concept is optionally made available.

Comment: Sure, and I think there is actually a shim available. I came to this question looking for the "ASP.NET 5 way of doing things" though, and had to find it elsewhere - your question asks "what is the equivalent code" which is IMHO congruent to "what is the new way of doing this" - which is what I was after. So I thought I would add this answer for the next person.

Comment: I was doing the Core and put in my middleware to catch 404s to redirect to 404 page, and came upon a problem where I wanted to _throw_ this error in lieu of a 500. This answer put me on the right track and I am using `return NotFound();` as the action's result when some server error occurs.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an extended version of @muhammad-rehan-saeed answer.
It logs exceptions conditionaly and disables http cache.
If you use this and UseDeveloperExceptionPage, you should call UseDeveloperExceptionPage *before* this.

**Startup.cs:**

```cs
app.UseMiddleware<HttpExceptionMiddleware>();
```

**HttpExceptionMiddleware.cs**

```cs
/**
 * Error handling: throw HTTPException(s) in business logic, generate correct response with correct httpStatusCode + short error messages.
 * If the exception is a server error (status 5XX), this exception is logged.
 */
internal class HttpExceptionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public HttpExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await this.next.Invoke(context);
        }
        catch (HttpException e)
        {
            var response = context.Response;
            if (response.HasStarted)
            {
                throw;
            }

            int statusCode = (int) e.StatusCode;
            if (statusCode >= 500 && statusCode <= 599)
            {
                logger.LogError(e, "Server exception");
            }
            response.Clear();
            response.StatusCode = statusCode;
            response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] = "no-cache";
            response.Headers[HeaderNames.Pragma] = "no-cache";
            response.Headers[HeaderNames.Expires] = "-1";
            response.Headers.Remove(HeaderNames.ETag);

            var bodyObj = new {
                Message = e.BaseMessage,
                Status = e.StatusCode.ToString()
            };
            var body = JsonSerializer.Serialize(bodyObj);
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(body);
        }
    }
}
```

**HTTPException.cs**

```cs
public class HttpException : Exception
{
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; }

    public HttpException(HttpStatusCode statusCode)
    {
        this.StatusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public HttpException(int httpStatusCode)
        : this((HttpStatusCode) httpStatusCode)
    {
    }

    public HttpException(HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message)
        : base(message)
    {
        this.StatusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public HttpException(int httpStatusCode, string message)
        : this((HttpStatusCode) httpStatusCode, message)
    {
    }

    public HttpException(HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message, Exception inner)
        : base(message, inner)
    {
    }

    public HttpException(int httpStatusCode, string message, Exception inner)
        : this((HttpStatusCode) httpStatusCode, message, inner)
    {
    }
}
```

I had better results with this code than with :

- UseExceptionHandler:

  - automatically logs every "normal" exceptions (ex 404).
  - disabled in dev mode (when app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage is called)
  - cannot catch only specific exceptions
- Opw.HttpExceptions.AspNetCore: logs exception when everything works fine

See also [ASP.NET Core Web API exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38630076/asp-net-core-web-api-exception-handling)

Answer (score 2):

Starting from ASP.NET Core 3 you can use `ActionResult` to return HTTP status code:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public ActionResult<ITEMS_TYPE> GetByItemId(int id)
{
...
    if (result == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(result);
}
```

More details are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-3.1