# Is there a way to throw a HttpException from codebehind in MVC asp.net core 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, http-status-code-404

I am trying to throw a simple HttpException 404 error from code behind in a class in MVC asp.net core 2 web application.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation you could use `StatusCodeResult`as the result:

```
public StatusCodeResult StatusCodeActionResult()
{
    return StatusCode(404);
}
```

For more information see [StatusCodeResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.statuscoderesult?view=aspnetcore-2.0)

Comment: This is for a Contoller class. I want to send back to the browser a 404 error code from a class dirived from RequestCultureProvider.

Comment: Well, it seems that the `RequestCultureProvider` is not designed to return something else than a `ProviderCultureResult` so maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054012/asp-net-5-mvc-6-equivalent-of-httpexception) could give you an idea - it simply creates an own `HttpException` and throws it. Or you will need to see whether `this` offers you access to the `Response` so you can set header tags manually?

Comment: I have tried to use the Response.StatusCode but Response.End() has been removed from core 2

Answer (score 0):

I created a middleware to handle custom exceptions but I think that’s not the best performance wise approach since core team says it’s not a good practice to throw exception to handle business logic. You can see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054012/asp-net-5-mvc-6-equivalent-of-httpexception) from [OlafW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320150/olafw) comments